# CSS or images to do a 5sided looking div

Tags: html, css

I have the following images that i use on li tags and li:hover. https://i.stack.imgur.com/myvRc.jpg

I'm using them for a tabbed look to a navigation bar. It works fine, but I do have some links that are larger in terms of text, so it doesn't fit. Instead of making multiple images for the navigation, I'm wondering if there is a way using CSS3 or background tiling to have it so the left side stretches wider when needed.

Here's the HTML(erb) i have:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Articles', articles_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'About Us', about_us_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Zen Moments', zen_moments_path %></li>
    <% if current_user %>
      <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use a tiling background for the actual `li`, and use `li::before` and `li::after` (with properly modified z-order, if needed) to build the left and right side of the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-image) could do this, if your text doesn't need to extend into the box containing the sloping area.

Comment: Took a look at that. What i ended up doing was splitting up the image left and right sides, and had those as div background images on the left and right side of the anchor tag. Then i applied the background and border properly, as well as the gradient for the onhover. I then used jQuery so the two side images change based on mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sliding door technique. There is a classic example on alistapart.
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/